# Creating JSON File From Parse Database

Tags: php, json, parsing, back4app

Does anyone know how to create a JSON file using data from a Parse Database (Back4App) using PHP?

Im needing to drop a file to my server each morning to populate a data  grid.

Answer (score 0):

Back4App use mongoDB (that uses JSON-like documents with schemas) , if you want to get the mongoexport, you're able to use the [Dashboard](https://help.back4app.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003457092-How-I-Can-export-my-Database-) or steps from [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) :)

And Parse Server have the guide to [PHP](http://docs.parseplatform.org/php/guide/) at Parse Server Docs!

In case of any other doubts, could you elaborate your question better? Please = D